# How to click on a table entry and search for it in another mongodb collection ( php / jquery )

Tags: php, jquery, mongodb

I filled my html table with documents from my MongoDB collection named "modules". My document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59859f9bd5234d8d415eb0ca"),
    "name" : "Module A",
    "weight" : 18,
    "components" : [ "cid1", "cid2","cid3", "cid4","cid5"],
    "color" : "blue"
}
```

**My HTML-row structure:**

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">1
    </th><td>Module A</td>
    <td>18kg</td>
    <td>
        <a href="cid1">Component 1</a>
        <a href="cid2">Component 2</a>
        <a href="cid3">Component 3</a>
        <a href="cid4">Component 4</a>
        <a href="cid5">Component 5</a>  
    </td>       
    <td>blue</td>
</tr>
```

**For my connection I used (found in a tutorial):**

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter = [];
$options = [
    'sort' => ['_id' => 1],
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('workshop.modules', $query);
```

**Document from "components" collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5985ca81d5234d8d415eb421"),
    "name" : "Component 2",
    "weight" : 1,
    "price" : 10,
    "color" : "blue"
}
```

**The following I don't know how to do:**

Klick on one of these components for example "Component 2". Search in another collection named "components" for this entry (with component name or id) and show information about this component an a new window or popup.

How can this be realize with php/jquery/mongodb?

PS: You can also change/improve my json structure if needed.

**UPDATE:**

Here ist my **app.php** source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Custom CSS for Table -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$filter = [];
$options = [
    'sort' => ['_id' => 1],
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('workshop.modules', $query);
?>
    <div class="form-group pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="What you looking for?">
    </div>
    <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
    <table class='table table-striped results'>
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Components</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
            <tr class="warning no-result">
      <td colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    $i=1; 
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $document->name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $document->weight;  ?>kg</td>
        <td>
            <?php 
            $components = $document->components;
            foreach($components as $component) {
                echo "<a class='component' href=$component>".$component."</a>  ";
            }
            ?>
        </td>       
        <td><?php echo $document->color;  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++;
    } 
    ?>
    </table>



    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Search function for table -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesearch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a working solution that works with my app.php. And of course you can adjust my app.php if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of many possible approaches:

Pass the component ID in a link, targeted to a new window, that calls a different PHP script that retrieves the document from the `components` collection and displays the data.

For example, a file `component.php` with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
/* ... */
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$filter = [
    '_id' => (string) $_GET['id']
];
$options = [];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('workshop.components', $query);
$document = reset($cursor); // select first result
?>
/* DISPLAY COMPONENT DETAILS HERE */
```

and in `app.php`, change the `href` for the component link to:

```
echo "<a class='component' href='component.php?id=$component'>".$component."</a>";
```